# Autoplay html5 audio on iPad workaround

Tags: ios, html

I've been looking into this issue and most sources say that it is not possible to autoplay audio on mobile iOS devices and there is no workaround.

However I have found that elearning software iSpring seems to export html files which do autoplay audio as it goes from one slide to the next:

http://www.ispringsolutions.com/resources/demo/pro/lets-brew-some-hebrew-1/index.html

This happens without any user interaction except the initial click to start the course off.

Looking into the resources I can verify that the mp3 files are separate and not just one long mp3 file with the whole course in it, but I can't figure out what kind of event happens at the end of slide 1 to start off the slide 2 audio.

Is there a way to replicate this effect? We would like to insert this functionality to a course exported in another type of e-learning software.

Comment: It's not "autoplay" if you need to tap to get the audio started. The user has to interact with the page only once, after that the page is free to play other audio without user interaction.